# How do I install the Zeven OS desktop environment on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: desktop-environments

Recently I've been interested in Haiku OS and I really liked the BeOS look it had, so I did some googling to see if somebody ported it to Linux but I couldn't find any.

However I did find a distro called ZevenOS, that looked very similar and I wanna see if I can install it's desktop environment in Ubuntu.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and currently using xfce as my main desktop environment, it'd be cool to try it out natively without having to format my PC or setting up a VM.

Here's a screenshot if anyone needs it: http://www.zevenos.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/2010-11-14-084023_1280x800_scrot.png

Comment: You need to ask them that, not us. Mind the biggest issue: BeOS was NOT Linux.  It had its own kernel. ZevenOS is based on a custom theme for the Xfce DE so basically you already have all the tools you need: start fiddling with the theme itself and see how far you get towards what ZevenOS uses. But again... you would be better off asking the creators of ZevenOS if it is possible to package it as a DE for Ubuntu itself.

Comment: Mind that their website http://www.zevenos.com/ does not give me a lot of confidence in their products. It errors out a lot and the latestet news is about 2014.

Comment: Oh so it's just a theme for Xfce, Interesting..
Also I'll try and contact them whenever I can, though I'm not confident that they'll respond, the distro itself hasn't been updated in a long time.

Though I did find a BeOS Xfce theme that looks close enough,
I guess I didn't use the right keywords.